# WARNs in Confluence 6.0.1 after upgrade

Tags: confluence, atlassian-crowd

I upgraded Confluence to 6.0.1. Also I use Crowd for SSO. All worked fine before upgrade. After upgrade it seems work good too, I can login into Confluence. But I the following WARNs have appeared in atlassian-confluence.log:

```
WARN [Caesium-1-4] [client.hash.reader.RemoteHashingInstructionsReader] readInstructions Unable to read remote instructions with key 'uid.onewayhash'.
WARN [Caesium-1-4] [analytics.client.hash.BcryptAnalyticsEmailHasher] create No instructions for hashing could be found.
```

What do this WARNs mean? How I can fix that WARNs?

I tried to search the solution in internet, but did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confluence collects analytics data about how you use the platform and reports it back to Atlassian. These warnings are part of that analytics package.

One way to get rid of these warnings is to turn off analytics.

Go to **Confluence administration | General Configuration | Analytics** and turn it off there.

[More info on Atlassian's data collection policy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/data-collection-policy-659783908.html).